# prevent watir-webdriver running chrome as a first run

Tags: google-chrome, watir-webdriver

Everytime I use watir-webdriver to initialise a chrome browser instance, it launches as a first-run with an EULA pop-up and an additional getting-started tab open.

Both of these side-effects are preventing me from automating tests for chrome.

I have tried initialising a browser using just

```
Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, :switches => %w[--no-first-run]
```

but have the same result.

I am surprised to be unable find any other questions online about this, so assume I have done something weird!

I have placed chromedriver.exe in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application` which is on my PATH variable.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution for this. In `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application` there is a file called master_preferences.

Opening this file and setting:

`require_eula` to `false`

`show_welcome_page` to `false`

fixed both issues for me.

Hopefully this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

I would put the chromedriver.exe on your PATH, so somewhere like C:/windows/system32 or the like, or you could add the directory
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application
to your PATH (right click My Computer -> Advanced -> Environment Variables)

It should then run OK.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but neither of these solutions work for me. I should have mentioned that `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application` is already in my PATH.. although if it wasn't chromedriver would not run at all.