# How to Start ChromeDriver.exe without EULA?

Tags: testing, google-chrome, selenium

I am learning to use Selenium (v2.20) to get ahead of some of our programmers who will soon be creating some browser tests with it. I'd like to uncover the pitfalls before they get there, and I've stumbled into one.

When I create my ChromeDriver, it always brings up a "Google Chrome EULA" and presents two buttons: "Accept and Run" and "Cancel". As I want this to be an automated test, having a user click a button is out of the question.

I looked at a list of [Chromium Command Switches](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) but did not find any that worked, nor any that mentioned EULA. The test works fine if I (at a breakpoint) click "Accept and Run" and then let the code continue.

The code, up to the line that causes the problem, is below:

```
using (var driverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"C:\Apps\ChromeDriver\"))
{
    driverService.Start();

    // This line pops up the EULA
    IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Apps\ChromeDriver\");

    // rest of test...
}
```

Has anyone else run into this issue? If so, how did you solve it?

*UPDATE 4/4/12*
I just ran the same code on my computer at work and I succeed without triggering the EULA (consistent with Slanec's experience). This leads me to believe the cause is environmental. I'm looking into the differences between the two systems (both Win7 x64) to determine the cause. I'll update once I have more information.

Thanks much,

-Seth

Comment: I just tried a fresh install of Google Chrome 18 with (Java) WebDriver and it worked as expected. If you open Chrome manually, does EULA show up? Which version of Chrome do you have? Is it an option for you to reinstall it and tyr again?

Comment: @Slanec - I've got both v1.8 and v1.9 of chromedriver.exe. They both exhibit the same behavior with the above code. My actual Chrome browser is v18, and does not ask for EULA, but that executable (chrome.exe) is not used in my testing. I am open to re-installing Chrome, but want to exhaust other options first. Thank you for commenting.

Comment: For future reference, the following answer worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9974379

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you still have this problem, the error occurs because you are opening up a brand new instance of the chrome browser every time you run the test, thereby triggering the EULA. If you copy the default chrome profile into a custom location of your choice, and then add the "--user-data-dir=yourcustomlocation" flag to ChromeOptions, you can bypass the EULA and open up the existing profile instead.

```
ChromeOptions crOptions = new ChromeOptions();
crOptions.AddArgument(@"--user-data-dir=C:\custom location"); 
return new ChromDriver(crOptions);
```

Answer (score 1):

Steps:

1. Copy your chromedriver.exe into Windows/System32
2. Now Go to your chrome folder, for me it is: C:\Users\"%USERNAME%"\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\
3. There is a master_preferences file.
4. Open it and false EULA option.

It works for me, hope will work for you all also.