# How to Start ChromeDriver.exe without EULA with Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, webdriver, customization, eula

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Start ChromeDriver.exe without EULA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936070/how-to-start-chromedriver-exe-without-eula)

When I create my ChromeDriver, it always brings up a "Google Chrome EULA" and presents two buttons: "Accept and Run" and "Cancel". I want this to be an automated test, so user click is not possible.

Please suggest how can I used ChromeDriver without EULA?

Comment: Did you try to run chrome manually and accepting the EULA? Because it does not happen to me... But i use Chrome a lot as my browser

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936070/how-to-start-chromedriver-exe-without-eula and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128261/chrome-driver-without-eula-by-python

Comment: Steps:
1.Copy your chromedriver.exe into Windows/System32 2. Now Go to your chrome folder, for me it is: C:\Users\"%USERNAME%"\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\ 3. Edit master_preferences file and make the changes false in EULA option.